# Store does not have a valid reducer - React Testing Library / Jest

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-testing-library, redux-toolkit

I switched our state management to redux toolkit. Now, of course, many tests fail, which I have to adapt accordingly. An error message is:

> console.error
> Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.

```
  2 | import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
  3 |
> 4 | export const store = configureStore({
    |                                    ^
  5 |   reducer: {
  6 |     result: resultsReducer,
  7 |   },
```

I have a test-utils.tsx file in which I override the render function as suggested in the Redux Toolkit documentation.

Here is the relevant part of it:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  result: resultsReducer,
});

const initialState: RootState = {
  // ...
};

const render = (
  ui,
  {
    store = configureStore({
      reducer: rootReducer,
      preloadedState: initialState,
    }),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {},
) => {
  const Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
  };
  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions });
};
```

I export the resultsReducer like this from an index.ts file:

```
import { resultsSlice } from './slices/resultsSlice';
export const { reducer: resultsReducer } = resultsSlice;
```

The slice looks like this:

```
export const resultsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'results',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    // ...
  },
});
```

Whats missing or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't provide the code that the error throws.

Comment: The code is within the store.ts and looks exactly like in the error message :)